# insert data multiple times based on number of days selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am new to php & mysql, I am trying to develop a movie ticket booking system.

but I am not able to figure out that how to add a movie show in database

below is the form for selecting movie, shows, hall, theater and no. of days show to be run.

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add_show.php">
    <table border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">

    Assign Show to Movie
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Select Theater<br />
    <select name="theater">
      <option value="1">Theater A</option>
      <option value="2">Theater B</option>
      <option value="3">Theater C</option>
      <option value="4">Theater D</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <td>
    Select Hall<br />
    <select name="hall">
      <option value="1">Audi 1</option>
      <option value="2" >Audi 2</option>
      <option value="3">Audi 3</option>
      <option value="4">Audi 4</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

    <td>
    Select Movie <br />
    <select name="movie">
    <option value="">Select Movie</option>

      <?php 
      $query = "SELECT movie_id, mname FROM movie where status='running'";
      $result = mysql_query ($query);
      while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value=".$r['movie_id'].">".$r['mname']."</option>"; 
      }


      ?> </select>
      </td>

      <td>Add show for Next Days?<br>

  <select name="ndays">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>
  </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>
    Select Show<br />
    <select name="hall">
      <option value="1">All Shows</option>
      <option value="2" >12:00 PM</option>
      <option value="3">3:00 PM</option>
      <option value="4">6:00 PM</option>
        <option value="5">9:00 PM</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="submit" value="add show" />

    </td>
    </tr>



    </table>
    </form>
```

now the problem is that I am not able to insert data in database.

there are few issues.

1. how to add date in database on basis of selection of no. of days?.
2. how to add all show with same movie name, theater and hall name?.

here is the php code of processing form

```
<?php

$theater= $_POST['theater'];

$hall= $_POST['hall'];

$movie= $_POST['movie'];
$count= $_POST['ndays'];

$showt=$_POST['showst'];



$arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
 if($showt==1)
 {
     $count1="4";
     for($i=1;$i<$count1;$i++)
     {
    //Dont know what to right here, I want to add 3 hours to showtime each time loop runs" 

     }

 }

$st=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime('$st')));



$arr[] = " ('$st','$movie', '$theater', '$hall', '$showt' )";


$sql = "INSERT INTO schedules VALUES(s_id, sdate, movie_id, theater_id, hall_id, show_id) VALUES ";
}


?>
```

Kindly help me out to solve this puzzled situation. I have submission in today evening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 datepicker for starting day and ending day of movie show..
Or you can use mktime() function to make date.

For All show for same movie ..you can use checkbox instead of select.
So, You can add multiple values..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO schedules VALUES(sdate, movie_id, theater_id, hall_id, 
show_id) VALUES ('$_POST['sdate'],'$_POST[movie_id]','$_POST[theater_id]',
'$_POST[hall_id],$_POST[show_id]')";
$sql1=mysql_query($sql);
```

You can make s_id auto increment from table.
Use your variable which is given in field name in form, i'm just show u demo from ur query.

Comment: can you help me out for the insert query?